# Turn off hardware button light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am using the following code:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = 
    IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

to prevent my night clock app from turning off.

However, the lights on the Back, Home, Search buttons never turn off. These are too bright for a nightstand clock app.

QUESTION - Any way to turn these off?

Thanks!
swine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage the light of hardware buttons. :(

Comment: As much as this answer makes me sad, i believe it is the correct one. On Nokia devices, the lights stay on during the app, and on Samsung devices, the lights go off... so seems that even the OS is not controlling this.

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying considering the fact that earlier versions of Windows Phone 7 didn't make the hardware buttons lit all the time, only when they were used. However now they don't turn off while the phone is in use and there doesn't appear to be any way to turn them off or to configure when they'll turn on or anything like that. Hopefully Microsoft will potentially not abandon Windows Phone 7 in favor of focusing solely on Windows Phone 8, but if they still do updates, I hope that hardware back light configurations will be one of them.